# Change dropdown index after downloading file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list having **Download** as one option

When ever user selects **Download** option, i am using Response to download the file. After downloading the file, i want to change the drop down list index to 0. I tried it by setting the selected index of drop down to 0 after downloading the file. But it is not at all wroking.
If any postback occurs after downloading the file, again **Download** option selected automatically in the drop down list.

I am calling the following method when **Download** option is selected.

```
protected void downloadfile()
{
         Response.Clear();
         Response.Buffer = false;
         Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
         Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
         Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
         Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         Response.Flush();
}
```

Please share your suggestions to resolve this....

Comment: a little bit of codes would be nice as a starting point for others.

Comment: I think first you need to positively identify when a file finished downloading. As far as i know there no such event which tell you if a file download successfully, there could be  work around using cookies and some javascript but i am not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue, by using Iframe.

As soon as the **Download** option is selected in the drop down,I am calling the javascript function **DownloadFile()** in the server side as follow:

```
protected void ddlSelectedAction_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, GetType(), "download", "DownloadFile();", true);

    // We can do what ever we want, You can redirect to another page or anything you want
    //Here I am changing the ddlSelectedAction selected index to 0
    ddlSelectedAction.SelectedIndex = 0;

}
```

Below is of that javascript function

```
DownloadFile()
{

    var filename= $get("Filename").value;

    // Point the IFRAME to GenerateFile, with the
    //   desired region as a querystring argument.
    iframe.src = "GenerateFile.ashx?fname=" + filename;

    // This makes the IFRAME invisible to the user.
    iframe.style.display = "none";

    // Add the IFRAME to the page.  This will trigger
    //   a request to GenerateFile now.
    document.body.appendChild(iframe); 
}
```

In the above function I am creating a Iframe, the source will be the handlerfile(GenerateFile.ashx) and any query string you can pass, that are used for downloading like **filename,filepath** etc.
In the pageload of handler file I am writing the code for downloading the file. Now we can do what ever operation we want after downloading the file.